# ODE Linear Independence using Wronskian

Tags: matlab, ode

> im trying to do a function that can check if x and y are linear
>   indepence or not given the general solution is
>
> > cx + dy = 0
>
> So this is how my code goes :
>
> ```
>     function myfun (x,y,n,n2)
> % sprintf('Input function respect to t');
> r = [1,x,y];
> % n=Degree of power in functions in f1
> % n2=input('Degree of power in functions in f2 
> syms t
> syms r
> if n==1 && n2==1
>     A=[r;diff(r,t,1);diff(r,t,1)];
>     W=det(A);
>     if W==0
>         sprintf('Linearly Independent');
>     else
>         sprintf('Linearly Dependent');
>     end
> end
> if n==1 && n2==2
>     A=[r;diff(r,t,1);diff(r,t,2)];
>     W=det(A);
>     if W==0
>         sprintf('Linearly Independent');
>     else
>         sprintf('Linearly Dependent');
>     end
> end
> if n==2 && n2==2
>     A=[r;diff(r,t,1);diff(r,t,2)];
>     W=det(A);
>     if W==0
>         sprintf('Linearly Independent');
>     else
>         sprintf('Linearly Dependent');
>     end
> end
> if n==2 && n2==4
>     A=[r;diff(r,t,1);diff(r,t,4)];
>     W=det(A);
>     if W==0
>         sprintf('Linearly Independent');
>     else
>         sprintf('Linearly Dependent');
>     end
> end When i try to run it for eg. myfun('2*t^2','t^4',2,4) , it gives error
> ```
>
> > Matrix must be square.
> >     Error in myfun (line 39)
> >     W=det(A);
>
> But when i run it separately, the code does work. Does this mean i
>   pass the function wrongly or does anyone can help me?

Edit: This my early code outline:

```
>> r=[1,2*t^2,t^4]

r =

[ 1, 2*t^2, t^4]

>>  A=[r;diff(r,t,1);diff(r,t,4)];
    W=det(A);
>> W

W =

96*t

>> A

A =

[ 1, 2*t^2,   t^4]
[ 0,   4*t, 4*t^3]
[ 0,     0,    24]
```

Comment: t and r are just scalar symbols in your code. Unless they are initialized to vectors, A is just another symbol - So A becomes just a 3 vector. Could you post the part of your code that runs?

Comment: @skm i put my early code outline that works

Answer (score 0):

Right - so you have supplied x and y as functions of t, but you have a new symbol t inside myfun defined by

```
syms t
```

That t has nothing to do with the t in terms of which x and y are defined. Also you have redefined r inside myfun!

So remove the redefinition of r and pass the t into the function like below:

```
function myfun(t,x,y,n,n2)
   r = [1,x,y];
   A=[r;diff(r,t,n);diff(r,t,n2)];
   W=det(A);
   if W==0
      fprintf('Linearly Dependent');
   else
      fprintf('Linearly Independent');
   end
end
```

Note that you don't need to test for each pair of n1 and n2 separately.

Also sprintf prints the result to a string

```
str = sprintf(...)
```

To print to screen, you need to use

```
fprintf(1, 'Linearly Independent');
```

The 1 indicates print to screen. If it was replaced by a file identifier, it would print to file. Look up the fprintf docs.

Now define t outside the function and call the function as:

```
syms t
myfun(t, 2*t^2',t^4, 1, 2)
```

Oh, and one more thing

```
W == 0 => L.Dependence
W ~= 0 => L.Independence
```